# React Native Webview custom html doesn't work with external link

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview, microstrategy

I'm trying to show a microstrategy demo dashboard on react-native-webview with microstrategy.dossier.create() method as recommend [microstrategy's documentation](https://github.com/MicroStrategy/embedding-sdk-samples/blob/master/page_navigation/src/App.js#L29) but everything is fine on simulators but doesn't work on **iOS real devices**. (Just show a blank space)

- Custom html to show micro dashboard:

```
  const html: string = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html">
      <title>MicroStrategy Dashboard</title>
      <!-- include the embeddinglib.js from the library -->
      <script src="https://demo.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/javascript/embeddinglib.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="showDossier()">
      <h2>Dashboard Demo</h2>
      <div id="myDossier" height="100%" width="100%" style="border: 1px solid red; height: "100%"; width: "100%"; "></div>

      <script>
          var BASE_URL = "http://demo.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary";
          var projectId = "EC70648611E7A2F962E90080EFD58751";
          var dossierId = "837B57D711E941BF000000806FA1298F";

          var placeHolderDiv = document.getElementById("myDossier");

          function showDossier() {
            var dossierUrl = BASE_URL + '/app/' + projectId + '/' + dossierId;
            window.microstrategy.dossier.create({
              placeholder: placeHolderDiv,
              url: dossierUrl,
              enableResponsive: true,
          });
          }
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
`;
```

- React return:

```
              <WebView
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                source={{
                  html,
                  baseUrl: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'http://localhost' : '',
                }}
                style={styles.webview}
```

I tried:

- Change baseURL to `http://localhost`.
- Change baseURL to `''`
- Delete baseURL prop and iOS return an alert ('The operation is insecure') and android return a `Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window'. Access is denied for this document.`
- With `baseUrl: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'http://localhost' : '',` works perfect on both simulators and android real device, but not on iOS real device

I think problem is about react-native-view baseURL prop, but I can't see where is the problem.
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

**Enviroment:**

```
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-native": "^0.72.6",
        "react-native-webview": "^13.6.2",
```

Comment: Verify the iOS App Transport Security (ATS) Settings:
Make sure that HTTP content loading is permitted in your iOS app. To turn off ATS, add the following key-value pair to your app's Info.plist file:

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work. I think problem is about third party's cookies.. This problem also occurs on safari Desktop and iOS Safari (and here, when you disabled third cookies, it's work). But I haven't solved yet :(